# Firebase scalability: Observer on whole data set vs multiple observers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm creating a Firebase Swift app where users can view messages posted by other users in a feed. Some messages are relevant to some users. Messages can be commented on and upvoted/downvoted.

Which is a more scalable design:

1) One observer that checks all messages' .Value and repopulate the feed.

2) One observer per message that a user has, and remove and add observers as feed updates.

1) sounds less scalable, but I'm worried about 2) having many observers and the latency behind adding and removing observers.

Which is a better design?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest a super simple approach. Add observers to the messages that include the user in question

So for example here's a posts (messages) node that stores posts.

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "post_0" : {
      "msg" : "some message",
      "user" : "uid_0"
    },
    "post_1" : {
      "msg" : "another message",
      "user" : "uid_1"
    },
    "post_2" : {
      "msg" : "yippee message",
      "user" : "uid_2"
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the code to observe any posts that include a reference to uid_2

```
    let postsRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("posts")
        postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("user").queryEqualToValue("uid_2")
           .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot)

    })
```

Once this code is run, any posts that are posted in the posts node that have a user = uid_2 will notify that user.

You can expand on this by changing up the post_x node for multiple users

```
  "post_0" : {
      "msg" : "some message",
      "users_watching_this_post"
         "uid_0": true
         "uid_2": true
    },
```

and a deep query

```
postsRef.queryOrderedByChild("users_watching_this_post/uid_2").queryEqualToValue(true)
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)
})
```